# Hostname for origin policy

Tags: numbers, port, hostname, policy

Does different host name with same domain name break origin policy?
Let me clarify my question.

```
[abc.xyz.net](abc.xyz.net)  
[pqr.xyz.net](pqr.xyz.net)
```

These two host name with same domain will break origin policy? And what if port number differs like:

```
[abc.xyz.net:8088](abc.xyz.net:8088)  
[pqr.xyz.net:8081](pqr.xyz.net:8081)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules

So

abc.xyz.net is different from pqr.xyz.net

is also 
abc.xyz.net:8088 is also different from pqr.xyz.net:8081

Hostname, port and protocol have to match. As everything can be used to exploit the information.

Comment: Thanks Jure , your answer is really helpful